# can`t remove selected face

Tags: edit-mode

I was trying to remove selected face.

So I entered edit mode and selected designated faces

[image]

pressed delete (face) and got below result

[image]

I don`t know why vertexes and edges still exist

How to remove this completely?

---

I have uploaded my project file.it is from the C-130 model made by manilov.ap in https://skfb.ly/6OR7z. (CC BY 4.0)

### [image]

do I missed something?

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Try to select the vértices of the circle and delet them

Comment: after face delete? no I can`t select any edges or vertices in edit mode(in edges, vertices mode)

Comment: probably because you had a duplicate of the wire frame. Try to first remove doubles.

Comment: @IgorSvara removed doubles but nothing is changed...

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots it is from https://skfb.ly/6OR7z I was trying to customize this model

Comment: ok but please share the part with the problem so that we can check

Comment: @moonboots have added project file sir

Comment: there are several windows, you should tell which one you tried, it looks like it works, maybe you've chosen X > Faces Only instead of X > Faces?

Comment: so I just checked the model and didn't have any problem deleting every single window, so be sure to select the part of the mesh you want to delete and press delete face not face only. Also, select all the mesh with A and merge by distance, because on the model you shared there are 600 double vertices.

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded gif and I have selected Faces not only Faces only. and was trying to remove all windows

Comment: @IgorSvara did I missed something? I have uploaded gif which contains whole process

Answer (score 3):

These are different objects.

[image]

You can edit them all together by selecting them and switching to edit mode.

[image]

By the way, Blender has .WRL importer:

[image]

but it seems to be broken for the recent versions.

[image]

[image]

Generally it is better to download original files from SketchFab because glTF messes them up.

[image]

[image]